# Issues running ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Tried adding the drivers to the right path. mentioned the path in the code and yet getting runtime errors with chromedriver. Cannot see what is wrong with the code. whats wrong?

Tried adding the path to the code. imported selenium and webdriver. placed the drivers in the python directory.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#to open the page in Chrome.firefox

driver = webdriver.Chrome("executable_path=D:\Python\Crawler\chromedriver_win32")
driver.get("http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html")
```

given Below are the errors:

```
D:\Python\Crawler\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/Crawler/crawler_sel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\vidwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\vidwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Crawler/crawler_sel.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("executable_path=D:\Python\Crawler\chromedriver_win32")
  File "D:\Python\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "D:\Python\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: is `webdriver.Chrome("executable_path=D:\Python\Crawler\chromedriver_win32")` the correct syntax? I assumed you had to set the path via environment variables?

Comment: backslashes are escape chars in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax here is off. It should be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Python/Crawler/chromedriver_win32.exe')
```

I've taken quotation marks off `executable_path`, and added `.exe` extension to your file path.

Alternative solution -- If you do not want to use `executable_path`, you can try adding `chromedriver_win32.exe` to your `Path` variable:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html")
```

Then, in your environment variable for `Path`, you have something like:

```
D:\Python\Crawler\chromedriver_win32.exe
```

This guide may help you with the `Path` part: https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf

Comment: backslashes are escape chars in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below this worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
#to open the page in Chrome.firefox
def set_up(self):
  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/Python/Crawler/chromedriver_win32.exe")
```